How to get constructor parameter types as a tuple in C++?
Unable to retrieve constructor arguments in a tuple.
I am trying to extract the constructor parameter types of a given class as a std::tuple. For example, if I have a class like this:
struct MyClass {
    MyClass(int, double, std::string) {}
};

I want to obtain a type like std::tuple<int, double, std::string> corresponding to the constructor parameters.
I am aware that in Boost.DI, this seems to be achievable since they manage to resolve constructor dependencies automatically. However, I couldn’t find a clear explanation of how they extract the constructor’s parameter types.
For regular functions, I know how to use std::tuple with templates, as shown below:
template <typename Func>
struct function_traits;

// Specialization for functions
template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct function_traits<Ret(Args...)> {
    using args_tuple = std::tuple<Args...>;
};

However, I am unsure how to adapt this approach for constructors.
Constraints:

I prefer solutions compatible with C++14 or C++17, but I am open to seeing approaches using C++20 or newer.
I am not opposed to using Boost or other libraries if necessary.

Could someone guide me on how to achieve this? Perhaps a minimal example or an explanation of how Boost.DI does it?
In case there are multiple constructors, boost di says it chooses the longest constructor. how does it do that too?
Example of how boost di works (from the official documentation).
ref : boost di exemple
// $CXX -std=c++14 basic_create_objects_tree.cpp
#include <boost/di.hpp>

namespace di = boost::di;

struct renderer {
  int device;
};

class view {
 public:
  view(std::string /*title*/, const renderer&) {}
};

class model {};

class controller {
 public:
  controller(model&, view&) {}
};

class user {};

class app {
 public:
  app(controller&, user&) {}
};

int main() {
  /**
   * renderer renderer_;
   * view view_{"", renderer_};
   * model model_;
   * controller controller_{model_, view_};
   * user user_;
   * app app_{controller_, user_};
   */

  auto injector = di::make_injector();
  injector.create<app>();
}

I think I have a clue using this file but I still can't fully understand the system and how I could implement it.
boost/di/type_traits/ctor_traits.hpp

its unclear how the example in the end is related to the question. You should explain what the code does or at least provide a link to the boost pages where this code is taken from

don't add "EDIT" for edits. The question should come as one concise version. If someone wants to know what has been added later on they can see the edit history https://stackoverflow.com/posts/79232950/revisions

The good thing about boost, it has its sources available to you... so what prevents you from having a look?

I've already spent a lot of time reading Boost Di. I thought that maybe someone would have a direct answer and that it could probably help other people since there is nothing on this subject. Stackoverflow is still my last alternative...

I think to retrieve std::tuple as argument, it requires stateful meta programming. providing a type with template conversion operator a la magic_get/boost::pfr.

If you want to obtain tuple type to store constructor arguments in order to store them and to invoke constructor later, then you don't need to deduce types of constructor arguments at all. You can use type erasure.

@Jarod42 Yes, some magic like that is probably needed and gaah... how annoying. I can easily get the argument count of the constructor taking the most argiments, but I can't figure out how to store the types :-)

@TedLyngmo: stateful metaprogramming see core14_loophole.hpp

Thanks for the answers. I don't think Boost Di uses a mechanism as complicated as 'The Great Type Loophole' but more simply with SFINAE.

@AlexisROARD I looked a bit at what Jarod42 sent and what I came up with myself. I'm pretty sure it must be complicated.

@TedLyngmo: Added answer aggregating your part and modified alexpolt's part (loophole meta-programming).

@Jarod42 Lovely! I was hoping you would take this on :-)

@Jarod42 ok, a big thank you it's impressive! I still have a lot to learn  thank you incredible!

First, count how many arguments they are (using Ted Lyngmo's code) (with hardcoded limit):
template<class T, std::size_t I>
struct Any {
    template<class U>
    operator U() const;
};

template <class T, size_t N>
struct is_valid_amount {
    static std::false_type test(...);

    template <std::size_t... Is>
    static auto test(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
        -> decltype(T(Any<T, Is>{}...), std::true_type{});

    static constexpr bool value =
        decltype(test(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}))::value;
};
template <class T, size_t N>
inline constexpr bool is_valid_amount_v = is_valid_amount<T, N>::value;

template<class T, std::size_t N>
struct ctor_def : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N> {
};

template <class T, std::size_t N = 16> // increase max amount of args if you wish
struct ctor_arg_count
    : std::conditional_t<is_valid_amount_v<T, N>,
                        ctor_def<T, N>,
                        ctor_arg_count<T, N - 1>> {};
template<class T>
inline constexpr std::size_t ctor_arg_count_v = ctor_arg_count<T>::value;

Then, with stateful metaprogramming, you might do:
namespace details
{
   template<std::size_t N> struct tag{};

    template<typename T, std::size_t N>
    struct loophole_t {
        friend auto loophole(details::tag<N>) { return std::type_identity<T>{}; };
    };

    auto loophole(tag<0>);
    auto loophole(tag<1>);
    auto loophole(tag<2>);
    auto loophole(tag<3>);
    auto loophole(tag<4>);
    auto loophole(tag<5>);
    auto loophole(tag<6>);
    auto loophole(tag<7>);
    auto loophole(tag<8>); // Add extra

    template <std::size_t N>
    struct detector {
        template <class T, std::size_t = sizeof(details::loophole_t<T, N>)>
        operator T();
    };

    template<typename T, typename Seq> struct ins;

    template<typename T, std::size_t... Is>
    struct ins<T, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
    {
        template <std::size_t = sizeof(T{detector<Is>{}...})>
        constexpr int operator()() const { return 0; }
    };

    template <std::size_t, std::size_t... Is, typename T = std::tuple<typename decltype(loophole(details::tag<Is>{}))::type...>>
    T get_type_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>);

    template <typename T, std::size_t N = details::ctor_arg_count_v<T>>
    auto get_type()
    {
        return details::get_type_impl<details::ins<T, std::make_index_sequence<N>>{}()>(std::make_index_sequence<N>());
    }

}

template <typename T>
using constructor_type_as_tuple_t = decltype(details::get_type<T>());

Demo
